# Servicestack doesn't have ProxyFeature with dotnet core?

Tags: .net-core, servicestack

Can't find ProxyFeature when using servicestack with dotnet core. Need help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ProxyFeature](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/ProxyFeature.cs) is in exactly the same place in .NET Core as it is for .NET 4.5, under the `ServiceStack` namespace. I've confirmed that it exists in v1.0.43 of **ServiceStack.Core** NuGet package that's published on NuGet:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I found the problem that  was cause by old version, I was using 1.0.41. After upgraded it to 1.0.43, everything showed up.